# Kubernetes service is getting external ip as pending

Tags: kubernetes

I running a kubernetes LB but the external ip says "pending", looks like it is trying to get a IP but, I need it as "localhost" to access it in my browser:

What do I miss?

```
NAME                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/dev-pypi     LoadBalancer   10.106.128.15   <pending>     80:30914/TCP     2m7s
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          47h
service/qa-pypi      LoadBalancer   10.97.62.94     <pending>     8200:30114/TCP   94m
```

Thanks in advance.
This is my yaml file:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: qa-pypi
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: pypi-qa
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8200
    targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: qa-pypi
  labels:
    app: pypi-qa
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pypi-qa
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pypi-qa
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pypi-qa
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        image: myimg2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
            - name: storageqa
              mountPath: /app/local
      volumes:
        - name: storageqa
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: persistvolumeqa
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: persistvolumeqa
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Thank you !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You tagged this with "minikube"; are you in fact running it under Minikube?  What is the attached image trying to show?

Comment: @DavidMaze it was showing the "pending " of the external IP, I just edited it
sorry

Comment: please clarify how you have created the cluster? also, add the output for `kubectl describe service`. further, if you want the local host and not external IP which is what the Loadbalancer service provide, use the `NodePort` service or better use `kubectl port-forward` for development/debugging purposes..

Answer (score 1):

You already have here a lot of advises how to use `localhost`, what you can do with `NodePort`. Let me fill the gap and explain why you see `Pending` state.

Look, minikube itself, doesnt allocate and provide you `LoadBalancer` ip-address. `LoadBalancer` service type is widely used in cloud implementations, like EKS, AKS, GKE and others. Because cloud service providers create you loadbalancer in the background as soon as you chose this type.

If you want to use `LoadBalancer` with minikube you should  configure minikube first. What you can do is use built-in [metallb](https://metallb.universe.tf/) minikube addon.

> MetalLB had addressed the gap and provides the network LoadBalancer
> implementation as an addon.

During metallb installation and configuration you are able to set the range og local ip-adressed that would be assigned to `LoadBalancer` service instead of `Pending` state

If you want to know more about this and check real example of configuration - check for example [MetalLB Configuration in Minikube — To enable Kubernetes service of type “LoadBalancer”](https://medium.com/faun/metallb-configuration-in-minikube-to-enable-kubernetes-service-of-type-loadbalancer-9559739787df) article

Answer (score 0):

you can use ingress to access your application from the browser
[ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

[settingup_ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/)

[tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80Ew_fsV4rM)

if you doesn't find your host after setup it may need to register at root `./etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   https-my-nginx.com
```

Answer (score 0):

To get expose your app in localhost you can try the NodePort type. If you are trying with kubeadm you can use NodePort type or ClusterIp type, so that you can able to expose it locally. Usually, Load-balancer is widely used in deployment on cloud machines.

If you are trying with minikube, then run `minikube tunnel` so that external-IP will be added for Loadbalancer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to configure external IP on your machine(platform) first then only external ip will be allocated to your service. It can be VIP which you can advertise or address pool needs to make, other wise setting up ingress will also not going to serve the purpose as ingress itself needs external IP to be allocated for communication.

it's a networking thing you need to setup on your private machine.

if you don't want to use this option then can go for node port with that you can access externally with nodeip:nodeport.